# how do I launch ranger from virtualenv

Tags: linux, python-3.x, virtualenv

I can't have it install system-wide, so I created a virtualenv, but now how do I launch it?

thanks

[github](https://github.com/hut/ranger) 
[website](http://ranger.nongnu.org/)

Comment: Inside your (activated) virtualenv: `pip install git+git://git.savannah.nongnu.org/ranger.git`, provided you don't mind using the recent development version.

Comment: solved my problem, thanks, why didn't it work when instead of pip install git+git://git.savannah.nongnu.org/ranger.git, I did pip install ranger?

Comment: Try `pip search ranger`: it'll tell you "ranger" is "A Python package for the manipulation of Range objects". I.e., there are multiple packages called ranger, and yours isn't the one in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). Perhaps if it ever gets into the default Python packages, it gets a different name.